# How to update a field in a database via email?

Tags: laravel

When a user subscribes to news from the site, he receives a welcome letter in his mail with a question, does he really want to subscribe to news?

Also in the letter there is a button that confirms his consent to the newsletter.

How can I make it so that when I click this button from an email, the values ​​​​in my database are updated?

This is my mail form `welcome.blade.php`

```
Welcome, User
<form action="{{route('welcome', $data->hash)}} method="POST">@csrf
    <button type="submit">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function welcome($hash) {
    \DB::table('config')->where('hash', $hash)->update(['agree' => 1]);
```

Route

```
Route::post('welcome', 'WelcomeController@welcome')->name('welcome')
```

Comment: You cannot add a form in an email. You need to add a link to confirm the consent. The link will redirect to your application and will trigger an action.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding forms in emails is not allowed/recommended. It is a security risk. Email clients will simply warn the recipients of potential danger and will disable the form.

You need to add a link to your application in the email content.

```
<a href="http://yourapp.com/add-consent/{$token}">click me</a>
```

When a user will click on the URL below route will hit.

```
Route::get('/add-consent/{token}', 'WelcomeController@welcome')->name('welcome');
```

In the action identify user based on token and perform the action.

```
public function welcome($token) {
// Identify user based on token and perform the action...
    \DB::table('config')->where('hash', $token)->update(['agree' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: `Route::post()` should be `::get()`.

Comment: GET seems irrelevant for me here. GET is used for viewing something, without changing it, while POST is used for changing something.

Comment: As you carefully (and accurately) explained in your answer, forms won't work in email, so you need a plain link.  Plain link -> click -> GET request: you need a `Route::get()` to handle that click.